# Data parsing from Livescore

Tags: java, jsoup

Given a specific football match in the premier league. I used livescore to get statistical data. I found the necessery rows in the web consol.

```
<div class="clear">
    ::before
    <div class="col-1 tright" data-type="home-stat">5</div>
    <div class="col-1 tleft" data-type="away-stat">1</div>
    ::after
</div>
```

I ran the folloving command in java

```
String url = "...";
Document html = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

html.select("[class=col-1 tright]").get(0);
html.select("[class=col-1 tleft]").get(0);
```

It retrived the folloving result without text attribute:`

```
<div class="col-1 tright" data-type="home-stat"></div>
<div class="col-1 tleft" data-type="away-stat"></div>
```

I know when i click on the match an script is going to running on the page.
But how can i extract the proper data wich in this case 5 and 1 ?

Comment: In `JavaScript` you can use `innerText`

Comment: Probably populated (post the url if you want more than guesses) with javascript, so have a look at htmlunit.

Comment: For example [Everton - Tottenham](http://livescore.com/soccer/england/premier-league/everton-vs-tottenham-hotspur/1-2252177/)